# Basic question on interchanging limits and integrals

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of measurable functions on $[0,1]$ such that $\int_0^1 \left| f_n^2 \right| \leq 1$ $ \forall n$, $f_n \to 0$ a.e. on $[0,1]$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int \left|f_n\right|\to 0.$

My approach was to try exploring around with $\int \left|f_n\right| \leq \left(\int \left| f_n \right|^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=1$ and trying to find from this some way to bound $f_n$ with some Lebesgue integrable function $g$ so I can pass the limit using Dominated Convergence. Intuitively, I know also that having function values $\left|f_n\right| \geq 1$ over a set of measure larger than zero will eventually "mess up" the integrals of the squares of the functions (in that they would be larger than $1$), but I'm not sure that's entirely correct. Not certain how to proceed from here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be fixed; by Egoroff's theorem, there is a measurable $A \subseteq [0,1]$ with $m(A) < \epsilon$ such that $f_n \to 0$ uniformly on $A^c$. So it is sufficient to bound $\int_A |f_n|$; but this is immediately done by Holder's inequality:

$$\int_A |f_n| = \int |f_n| \chi_A \le \|f_n\|_{L^2} \|\chi_A\|_{L^2} \le 1 \left(\int_A 1\right)^{1/2} = m(A)^{1/2} < \epsilon^{1/2}$$

which is good enough.

---

Examples can be constructed where there is no $L^1$ dominating function, so sadly that approach won't work directly.

Comment: Oh, right! This question had the feel that there was an important theorem right on the tip of my tongue, and that's the piece I needed. Thanks!!

Comment: You're very welcome.